# Rails: create and destroy belongs_to association through link_to actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an admin interface where I have images and heroes. The hero table consists in only two columns: id and image_id. I would like to be able to add and remove images to the hero table.

I have a select_to_hero and select_from hero action and view which display either all images not already connected or all existing heroes and both work, but the add_to_hero and remove_from_hero actions, which I use to create a new or destroy an existing association do not work.

Hero.rb Model

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image_id
  belongs_to :image
end
```

Image.rb Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alt, :author, :copyright, :file_name, :title
  has_one :hero
  mount_uploader :file_name, ImageUploader
end
```

Select_from_hero.html.erb

```
<% @heroes.each do |hero| %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag(hero.image.file_name.url(:thumb), {:action => 'remove_from_hero', :id => hero, :hero => @hero}) %>
<% end %>
```

Select_to_hero.html.erb

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag(image.file_name.url(:thumb), {:action => 'add_to_hero', :id => image, :hero => @hero}) %>
<% end %>
```

images_controller.rb

```
def add_to_hero
  @hero.image << Image.find(params[:id]) unless @hero.image.include?(Image.find(params[:id]))
  if @hero.save
    ..
  else
    render :action => 'select_to_hero'
  end
end

def remove_from_hero
  @hero.image.delete(Image.find(params[:id]))
  if @hero.save
    ..
  else
    render :action => 'select_from_hero'
  end
end
```

With this setting I get:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ImagesController#add_to_hero
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ImagesController#remove_from_hero
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

But I can query an existing association:

```
> Hero.find(2).image
  Hero Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `heroes`.* FROM `heroes` WHERE `heroes`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Image id: 1, file_name: "red.jpg", title: "blu", alt: "yellow", author: "John", copyright: "Jane", created_at: "2019-01-29 19:50:25", updated_at: "2019-01-29 19:50:25">
```

How can I get this working?

## Update

Routes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :heroes
  match '/images/select_to_hero',        :to => 'images#select_to_hero',    :as => :select_to_hero
  match '/images/select_from_hero',      :to => 'images#select_from_hero',  :as => :select_from_hero
  resources :images
  match '/images/add_to_hero/:id',       :to => 'images#add_to_hero',       :as => :add_to_hero
  match '/images/remove_from_hero/:id',  :to => 'images#remove_from_hero',  :as => :remove_from_hero
  ...
end
```

I had to move the `select_to_hero` and `select_from_hero` routes above `resources :images` or a call would have triggered the `show` action.

Comment: How do you find `@hero` in `add_to_hero` and `remove_from_hero` images? And add routes.rb, please

Comment: @Vasilisa. Hello! In this case I would probably have to create a new hero entry and not find @hero, since I can choose only between images not already present in the hero table. Probably something like `@hero.create_image(params[:image])`?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. You have `@hero` in controller actions, but I can't see - where and how you define it? Do you have some before filter for it? Your issue is in undefined `@hero`, that's why you get the error

Comment: No problem, my fault! I have a hero controller and before posting the question I deleted `:hero => @hero` in the link_to call from both html snippets, but it is still there. I deleted it when working on the code. Sorry but this part is the one I know about the least.

Comment: @Vasilisa. You are right. I messed up something. Since this is a simple belongs_to association between two resources, which is either created or destroyed, and no join table, etc. I would have to create and destroy an entry in the hero table. Something like `@hero = Hero.new(:image => params[:image])` and `@hero = Hero.find(params[:id])` + `@hero.destroy`.

Comment: @Vasilisa. The `remove_from_hero` action works with `@hero = Hero.find(params[:id])` + `@hero.destroy`, but the `add_to_action` produces `undefined method `stringify_keys' for "2":String` with `@hero = Hero.new(params[:id])` where 2 is the id of the image to be connected.

Comment: @Vasilisa hello, thanks to your advice I might have found a solution. I had to use `:action => 'add_to_hero', :id => image, :image_id => image` and create a Hero entry by `@hero = Hero.new(:image_id => params[:id])`. I hope that is sound. Thank you very much as always for you comments and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the always helpful @vasilisa I figured out a way to solve my problem. I had to use:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag(image.file_name.url(:thumb)), {:action => 'add_to_hero', :id => image, :image_id => image}) %>
<% end %>
```

in my view and:

```
def add_to_hero
  @hero = Hero.new(:image_id => params[:id])

  if @hero.save
    ...
  else
    render :action => 'select_to_hero'
  end
end
```

in my controller action.

This works, since in my case I only needed to declare an image as a hero by creating a new entry into Hero or to remove a hero declaration by destroying an entry in Hero.

Thanks all for their advice.

Answer (score 1):

follow up your last comment about your add_to_action, I would like to suggest solution below

Select_to_hero.html.erb, change :hero and send only the id of hero like this below

```
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
      <%= link_to(image_tag(image.file_name.url(:thumb), {:action => 'add_to_hero', :id => image, :hero_id => @hero.id}) %>
    <% end %>
```

images_controller.rb, find the hero first from the hero_id

```
    def add_to_hero
      @hero = Hero.find(params[:hero_id])
      @hero.image << Image.find(params[:id]) unless @hero.image.include?(Image.find(params[:id]))
      if @hero.save
        ..
      else
        render :action => 'select_to_hero'
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @widjajayd I figured out a solution. I had to use `{:action => 'add_to_hero', :id => image, :image_id => image }` in the call and `@hero = Hero.new(:image_id => params[:id])` in the controller action. I think I do not need to find an entry in Hero, because I do not update, but only create e new entry in Hero. I verified your solution and it gives me `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id` while calling the view. Anyway thank you very much.